# Support of an exponential family in canonical form

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable in the exponential family, with pmf/pdf 
$$f(y) = \exp\left[\sum_{j=1}^{s}\theta_jT_j(y)-B(\theta)+c(y) \right]$$
for $y \in \Omega$ (the support of $Y$), and where 
$$\theta = \begin{bmatrix}
\theta_1 \\
\theta_2 \\
\vdots \\
\theta_s\end{bmatrix}$$
is the canonical parameter.

> I wish to show that
>
> $$\Omega = \{y:\exp[c(y)] > 0\}\text{.}$$
>
> where $\Omega$, the support of $Y$, is defined by $\{y: f(y) > 0\}$.

The Google searching I've found either just mentions this as a fact, or states that it's obvious. And I don't see why it is.

If we set $f(y) > 0$, we obtain
$$\exp\left[\sum_{j=1}^{s}\theta_jT_j(y)\right]\exp[-B(\theta)]\exp[c(y)] > 0$$
or
$$\exp\left[\sum_{j=1}^{s}\theta_jT_j(y)\right]\exp[c(y)] > 0\text{.}$$
The problem is, though, how does this imply that $\exp[c(y)] > 0$? Why is it that we ignore $\exp\left[\sum_{j=1}^{s}\theta_jT_j(y)\right]$?

Comment: Can you find a number $x$ such that $\exp\{x\} \leq 0$?

Comment: @jbowman No, as long as $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (not allowing for $-\infty$).

Comment: So $\exp[c(y)] > 0$ because it can't be otherwise.

Comment: @jbowman I was doubting myself when I thought of something similar, because it seemed too simple... thanks!

Comment: Been there, done that!